# Elixir/Phoenix/Guardian - Assigning current_user in conn doesn't work for testing

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

If have some controllers like this

```
def index(%{assigns: %{current_user: %User{} = current_user}}} = conn, params) do
    ## User exists
end

def index(conn, params) do
    ## No user exists
end
```

If I run this test, I expect it to call the first #index action, but it calls the second action, with no users, and by conn assigns are `%{current_user: nil}`

```
test "GET /posts", %{conn: conn} do
    user = insert(:user)
    conn = assign(conn, :current_user, user)
    get(conn, post_path(conn, :index))
end
```

Why isn't the current_user being assigned properly? Why is it disappearing?

Comment: “If I run this test”—which test?

Comment: @mudasobwa It's as controller test.

Comment: Have you tried using Specifically ‘Plug.Conn.assign’ in test

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but try this instead

```
def index (conn,params)
 current_user = conn.assigns.current_user
## User exists
end
```

try this

Comment: If this would have worked, then his first function would have pattern matched.